# How to compute all possible combinations of multiple vectors/matrices of different sizes and sum up columns simultaneously?

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

Assume I have three matrices...

```
A=matrix(c("a",1,2),nrow=1,ncol=3)
B=matrix(c("b","c",3,4,5,6),nrow=2,ncol=3)
C=matrix(c("d","e","f",7,8,9,10,11,12),nrow=3,ncol=3)
```

I want to find all possible combinations of column 1 (characters or names) while summing up columns 2 and 3. The result would be a single matrix with length equal to the total number of possible combinations, in this case 6. The result would look like the following matrix...

```
Result <- matrix(c("abd","abe","abf","acd","ace","acf",11,12,13,12,13,14,17,18,19,18,19,20),nrow=6,ncol=3)
```

I do not know how to add a table in to this question, otherwise I would show it more descriptively. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We don't want to assume "....". We expect you to produce code that creates the presumptions upon which tested code can be delivered. If you cannot create a matrix in R then you should take 10 steps back and do some extra study.

Comment: I've truly no idea what you're asking for. Please write sample `A`, `B`, and `C` and your expected output.

Comment: My apologies, I was focused on getting a table placed into my question, and of course I should have simply added in the code. I hope this is helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `character` and `numeric` values in a matrix and this will coerce all elements to `character`. Much better to define your matrix as numeric and keep the `character` values as the row names:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1,dimnames=list("a",NULL))
B <- matrix(c(3,4,5,6),nrow=2,dimnames=list(c("b","c"),NULL))
C <- matrix(c(7,8,9,10,11,12),nrow=3,dimnames=list(c("d","e","f"),NULL))
#put all the matrices in a list
mlist<-list(A,B,C)
```

Then we use some `Map`, `Reduce` and `lapply` magic:

```
res <-  Reduce("+",Map(function(x,y) y[x,],
               expand.grid(lapply(mlist,function(x) seq_len(nrow(x)))),
               mlist))
```

Finally, we build the rownames

```
rownames(res)<-do.call(paste0,expand.grid(lapply(mlist,rownames)))
#    [,1] [,2]
#abd   11   17
#acd   12   18
#abe   12   18
#ace   13   19
#abf   13   19
#acf   14   20
```

Comment: Only other question, is there a way to change the row name to read "a, b, d" instead of "abd"